# Using substr() to delete a character

Tags: r, string, character, substr

I have a character `"abc"` and want to delete the `"b"`. I want to target by position. I tried:

```
x <- "abc"
substr(x, 2,3) <- ""

x
#[1] "abc"
```

Why is it not possible to delete a character from a string like this? How would I do it in a similarly simple approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you *"want to target by position"*, if what you mean is that you want to extract the second character from your string regardless of its value, then you can simply do:

```
x <- paste0(substr(x, 1, 1), substr(x, 3, nchar(x)))
# "ac" if x <- "abc" initially and "acd" if x <- "abcd" initially
```

You can replace a character with `substr()` but not remove it (since you need to shift the position of all following characters, etc.). To achieve this you could combine `substr` and `gsub` like this (e.g. if you are sure your string doesn't contain dashes):

```
substr(x, 2, 3) <- '-'
gsub('-', '', x)
```

If what you want is to remove the `"b"` occurences then `gsub()` as explained in the answers above is a good option.

Comment: I think thats the simplest solution, however:
If I do 

    x <- "abc"  and then 
    substr(x,2,3) <- "hello"
will actually change x. Therefore I think the second part of your answer is not correct.

Comment: You are right, my bad. But it works to replace a character and not to remove it. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially, you could just use `sub/gsub` here:

```
gsub("b", "", x)
```

But this would remove all `b` letters, regardless of where they appear.  If you wanted to target `b` sandwiched between only `a` and `c`, you could get clever and use lookarounds:

```
gsub("(?<=a)b(?=c)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

**Edit:**

As @DavidKlotz pointed out in his comment below, if you really want to remove the second character, you could use:

```
gsub("(?<=^.).","", x, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to remove any character in position 2.  Following on your suggestion, one could also do something like this, remembering that regex indices begin at 0: `gsub("(?<=^.{1})(.)","", x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @DavidKlotz Thanks for the suggestion, which I slightly modified above.  It helps to read the entire question: `I want to target by position.`

Comment: or `gsub(paste0("(?<=^.{",n-1,"})."),"", x, perl=TRUE)` to generalize it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the empty string is not supported.

The easiest way I see to hack it is to use a character that can't possibly be in your data then `gsub` it out:

```
x <- "abc"
substr(x, 2,3) <- "\a"
x <- gsub("\a","",x)
x
# [1] "ac"
```

You can of course use `gsub` directly as other suggested, but I assumed replacing by index was an important feature.

`\a` is a bell character, from Wikipedia:

> A bell code (sometimes bell character) is a device control code
>   originally sent to ring a small electromechanical bell on tickers and
>   other teleprinters and teletypewriters to alert operators at the other
>   end of the line, often of an incoming message

So you're probably safe!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `strsplit` which is useful If you want to tackle this problem by position (i.e. in your case remove 2nd letter),

```
paste(strsplit(x, '')[[1]][-2], collapse = '')
#[1] "ac"
```

To apply on multiple strings, we need to iterate after splitting, i.e.

```
x <- c('abc', 'sdfre', 'xyz')
sapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(i)paste(i[-2], collapse = ''))
#[1] "ac"   "sfre" "xz"
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, maybe R developers call that simple... What are those indices? -2 for the second letter? Why [[1]]?
And why does my approach fail?

Comment: Let me demonstrate with multiple strings.

Comment: I think `paste0(substr(x, 1, 1), substr(x, 3, nchar(x)))` is a better option maybe here (cf. my answer bellow), and quicker one in terms of perf. What's needed is to remove a single character, so I think splitting the string into characters is a bit of an overkill, don't you think?

Comment: @Pascallv, the `-2` just means "take all elements except the one with the index 2", and the `[[1]]` is because `strsplit()` returns a list where the first element is the splitted string, so it is to select the splitted string.

Comment: @Sotos, mine also uses the position 2 (1 = 2-1 and 3 = 2+1), and it's not a matter of how much functions are called. But I agree that both are acceptable solutions :) It's just that the question specifies "using `substr`"...

Answer (score 0):

you should use the gsub() function :
    `gsub(pattern = "b",replacement = "",x = x)`

Comment: This is the same as @Tim Biegeleisen's answer